# Python - Filter numpy array filter element values for all other element at same index without loop

Tags: python, numpy

Let's assume that I have a numpy array, as below:
The shape of the array is (5,3) has more than 1 million rows, and is typed as a numpy object.

Sample array:

```
x = np.array([['A',1,10],['B',1,20],['C',2,80],['D',3,40],['E',2,50]])
```

I would like to achieve the following:

If the value of column Y exists in another row(s) but only in column Y in the entire array set, then check value of the column X and they are not equal then filter record.

```
Col X  Y   Z

[['A' '1' '10'] ---> filter value '1' from the all values of column Y in entire array
 ['B' '1' '20'] ---> filter value '1' from the all values of column Y in entire array
 ['C' '2' '80'] ---> filter value '2' from the all values of column Y in entire array
 ['D' '3' '40'] ---> filter value '3' from the all values of column Y in entire array
 ['E' '2' '50']] ---> filter value '2' from the all values of column Y in entire array
```

**For example:** 
While checking for row number 1, column y value is **'1'** and for the same row, column x value is **'A'**. So first filter based on column y value '1'; the following rows satisfy the condition.

`[['A' '1' '10']`

`*['B' '1'* '20']]`

Then apply the second filter based on the value of column x in row 1, which is **'A'** not equal to the value of all other filtered rows column x.

So in this case, row 2 satisfies the both conditions.

`['B' '1'* '20']]`

Note: This example shows two matching records, but in actuality, it can be one or more than one, and it can be at any row position.*

Next thing, I would like to perform is, for selected record(s)(in this case row 2), append to row 1.

Please suggest

I tried this code but no lick:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([['A',1,10],['B',1,20],['C',2,80],['D',3,40],['E',2,50]])
y = x
print(x)
print("Result is:",x[np.where(x[:,1] == y[:,1], np.where(x[:,0] != y[:,0][::-1]),False)])

x=  --->print(x)

[['A' '1' '10']
 ['B' '1' '20']
 ['C' '2' '80']
 ['D' '3' '40']
 ['E' '2' '50']]
```

Result is: **empty**

Comment: The logic is unclear, you don't seem to demonstrate rows that should not be filtered in your example. Also why are you using numpy if you potentially have mixed types?

Comment: Apologies if I was not able to explain it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your expected result actually something like that?:

```py
arr = [
    ["A", 1, 10],  # 0
    ["B", 1, 20],  # 1
    ["C", 2, 80],  # 2
    ["D", 3, 40],  # 3
    ["E", 2, 50],  # 4
    ["F", 1, 30],  # 5
    ["A", 1, 70],  # 6
]

expected_indexes = [
    (1, 5),
    (0, 5, 6),
    (4,),
    (),
    (2,),
    (0, 1, 6),
    (1, 5),
]

expected = [
    (["B", 1, 20], ["F", 1, 30]),
    (["A", 1, 10], ["F", 1, 30], ["A", 1, 70]),
    (["E", 2, 50]),
    (),
    (["C", 2, 80]),
    (["A", 1, 10], ["B", 1, 20], ["A", 1, 70]),
    (["B", 1, 20], ["F", 1, 30]),
]
```

If so, you can do the following:

```py
X, Y = arr[:, :2].T
cond1 = Y[:, None] == Y[None, :]
cond2 = X[:, None] != X[None, :]
mask = cond1 & cond2
```

```py
>>> cond1
array([[ True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True]])
```

```py
>>> cond2
array([[False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False]])
```

```py
>>> mask
array([[False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False]])
```

And then work with the mask, the indices of `True` values in each row correspond to the `expected_indexes`.

From here I don't see how you can work without for loops, but the heavy lifting is already done and you don't have structured arrays anymore anyway:

```py
>>> indexes = [tuple(np.where(r)[0]) for r in mask]
>>> assert indexes == expected_indexes
>>>
>>> result = [tuple(arr[list(inds)]) for inds in indexes]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your code is working correctly as per requirement. How can I avoid for loop. I really don't want to perform for loop for larger data set.

Comment: As I said, since you don't have a structured array anymore you can't go without for loops, afaik. You could but you will only get a flat version of the result, maybe that fits your need: `np.broadcast_to(arr, (arr.shape[0], *arr.shape))[mask]`

Answer (score 0):

Your answer nest two `np.where`, the really works is `np.where(x[:,0] != y[:,0][::-1])`, it return indices of x which columns Y is same but columns X are not equal.

What you have to do is send indices to x.

```
Print('The answer is', x[np.where(x[:,0] != y[:,0][::-1])])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, this is not working as per expectation.  You code is returning:
 [['A' '1' '10']
 ['B' '1' '20']
 ['D' '3' '40']
 ['E' '2' '50']].


Original array (x) & expected result: 
For first row of x [['A' '1' '10']  expected result is [ ['B' '1' '20']]

For second row x ['B' '1' '20']  expected result is [['A' '1' '10']]

For third row x ['C' '2' '80']  expected result is [['E' '2' '50']]

For fourth row x ['D' '3' '40']  expected result is None []

For fifth row x ['E' '2' '50']]  expected result is [['C' '2' '80']]